# Prove or disprove, If A ≤p B and B is NP-hard, then A is in NP-hard

Tags: complexity-theory, p-vs-np

Intuitively if A can reduce to B, and B is NP-Hard, A might be NP Hard but maybe not. If there is a way to solve A that does not involve reducing to B, it might be faster.

How do I formally disprove this statement using a counter example or some well known algorithms, or using some other technique?

Answer (score 1):

Let A be the empty language. It is trivially reducible to, say 3SAT: transform any input into the formula $a \land \lnot a$. But only the empty language is reducible to the empty language, thus A is not NP-hard.

If P = NP, then any nontrivial language is NP-hard, thus it will be really hard to find counterexamples where both A and its complement are nonempty.

Comment: can you clarify what empty language is? Is this a SAT where all clauses contain only  and ¬ ?

Comment: In decision problems we are asked to determine if the input string is in the language. An empty language is the language containing no strings.